# Failed to push some refs to a repo that doesn't exist anymore

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push to a newly created repo and receive the following

```
failed to push some refs to 'http://github.com/...../.git'
```

This is an earlier repo.  I decided to download a zip copy and delete it from github, but now I get the edit saying the original repo above doesn't exist anymore and I still can't push to the new repo I created.

I'm very new to git and I'm wondering if it's worth deleting the github account and starting a new one. I've even deleted git from my system and reinstalled it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: _"I decided to download a zip copy and delete it from github"_ Why? What is your goal here exactly?

Comment: I _can_ tell you that randomly reinstalling software and nuking accounts isn't likely to make anything better. Stop deleting things!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't panic. Don't delete your Github account.

Check `git remote -v` to see what remote repositories your local is pointing at. It should look something like this:

```
origin  https://github.com/wrong/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/wrong/repo.git (push)
```

Change your origin remote to the new repo.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/right/repo.git
```

See [`git-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) and [Working With Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) in Pro Git for more.

---

> I decided to download a zip copy and delete it from github, but now I get the edit saying the original repo above doesn't exist anymore and I still can't push to the new repo I created.

There's few reasons to download a zip only to upload it to a new repository. You will lose the history of changes.

You can [rename](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-repository?algolia-query=rename+repository) and [transfer ownership](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository) on Github. If it's someone else's repository and you want your own copy, [make a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-forks).

With this in mind, you can [restore the deleted repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/restoring-a-deleted-repository).